# Github Markdown: Find emoji for the flag of Brazil

Tags: github, emoji, github-flavored-markdown

I am trying to use the Brazilian flag using markdown. But it is not as straightforward as I thought. That is to say writing `:pt-BR:` like for the American flag (`:us:`) or the Italian flag (`:it:`).

I found lots of repositories and lists, but none of them showed the flag I was looking for.

Is it possible to use the Brazilian flag, or get it into my `README.md` on Github?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. It's a valuable insight for my next questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use

```
<span>&#x1f1e7;&#x1f1f7;</span>
```

or simply copy and paste the unicode character from http://emojipedia.org/flag-for-brazil/ (or from here: )

[Demo](https://gist.github.com/jnizet/eb1f19ddd8fbe45287a4ce6a2c844ce1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still I get this: [Brazilian Flag](http://i.imgur.com/Oeb0deb.png).

Comment: Well, actually displays on the latest Safari for iPhone. Thank you for the support.

Comment: Great answer but emoji flags are not supported in Chromium browsers on windows. Best option would be an svg or png image from https://flagpedia.net/

Answer (score 6):

This should be much easier and works :

```
:brazil:
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Many other flags seem to be missing on GitHub servers as well (Portugal, Belize, ...).